# install oracle java8 on debian

Tags: java, debian-based, launchpad

Hi Guys it seems the WebUpd8 Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer is discontinued

```
https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
```

I have an application that is build by wercker and deploy into aws ecs cluster. The pipeline is broken as the oracle java 8 is no longer available in launchpad. Is there any alternative method we can install oracle java8 in debian?

Comment: Maybe you could use OpenJDK instead, since the reason why the package no longer exists is that "Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates"

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking, but Oracle Java 8 is going to be EOL very soon. Either you go with openjdk or you go with the new LTS releases from Oracle. Also, be careful with their new license terms. Anyway, you can try and fiddle a bit with the rpm distribution from the official [download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and manage to install it on debian.

Comment: Since we are suggesting different brands of java 8 then asked for: [Amazon Corretto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html) is available as debian package.

Comment: Thanks Guys, it is fixed by installing openjdk... @FedericoklezCulloca